# Capistrano - undefined method `map'

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am using capistrano through [Magentify](https://github.com/alistairstead/Magentify). I am using RVM as a regular user on archlinux. I have it using Ruby 2.0.0 and I ran `gem install magentify` in a gemset I defined for this purpose. It installed Capistrano 3.0.1 and a about 9 other gems. When I set the recipe, I tried

```
cap -T
```

and it writes

```
cap aborted!
undefined method `map' for :except:Symbol
/home/dirtymikeandtheboys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/magentify-0.0.6/lib/nonrails.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I also tried `cap deploy` with the same result (not sure what I expected.) How do I get started trying to fix this?

Edit: ran `--trace` with command `cap -T`:

```
cap aborted!
undefined method `map' for :except:Symbol
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:304:in `set_arg_names'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:29:in `define_task'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:360:in `define_task'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:32:in `task'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/magentify-0.0.6/lib/nonrails.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:196:in `in_namespace'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:104:in `namespace'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/magentify-0.0.6/lib/nonrails.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/magentify-0.0.6/lib/mage.rb:1:in `load'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/magentify-0.0.6/lib/mage.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dirtymike/public_html/project/Capfile:3:in `load'
/home/dirtymike/public_html/project/Capfile:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/dirtymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you checked your recipe for the occurrence of `:except`?

Comment: I do not see any in my capfile or deploy.rb

Comment: Don't suppose you have s stack trace you can post?

Comment: Capistrano 3 is quite new, there is a big chance this library was designed and tested with Cap 2, you should try that version and see if it works.

Comment: added it! ran with `--trace`

Comment: Tested again with capistrano 2.5.10 with same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT*

This is fixed in version 0.0.7 of the Gem. I submitted a patch and it now forces to Capistrano 2.X, which is the only compatible version. The original answer was wrong, the problem was not with Rake.

*Original Answer*

It seems that the problem is with Rake and not with Capistrano. You may need to, either use an older version of rake (possibly 0.9.6), or update the Magentify gem to work with rake 10. Maybe you can open an issue on that repo.

EDIT

Confirmed: It works with rake 0.9.6.

You can add this Gemfile to your project:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '~> 0.9'
gem 'magentify'
```

and then running it like `bundle exec cap -T`